# Data format used when working with LIMMA in R

Tags: r, bioconductor, limma

Can someone please give me a small example of what the microarray data that I import into LIMMA should look like when I import it into R?

I am trying to decipher differentially regulated genes from a microarray sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tab (or whatever) separated file with normalized expression levels with in addition a column with probeset ids (or other gene identifiers) and a header which defines samples - generally speaking.

To get an example of the needed code I suggest you to inspect a geo2r generated script (accessible from any GEO dataset) and to read the limma vignette.